# Need to update journey and send email accordingly

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In sales cloud contact object i have a field called "Mailing Status" its a multiselect picklist which has one value called "First Sales order".

Scenario - I want to create a journey builder in which i am selecting the same data extension which will get update from sync data extension through query.

So , once the criteria met email should be trigger to those subscriber which have mailing status contains first sales order.

Is this the best way to do or do i need to select salesforce data with the target objec and add filter?

Please suggest !!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use SQL for your target audience, then yes, this is the way to proceed.

However this means you'll need to schedule an Automation for the SQL Activity to run, which is at most once in hour.

Since you have Sales Cloud and Marketing Cloud connected, you can use the **Salesforce Data Entry Event** in the Journey Builder, this way you can 'listen' to the Sales Cloud changes and instantly inject the Contact to the Journey if the `Mailing Status` field picklist is changed to have the `First Sales order` value.

More information - [Salesforce Data Event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5)

Comment: Can we schedule journey with salesforce data as an entry event ? I am not able to see the option for scheduling .

Comment: How would you like to schedule it? Since the SF event acts based on events in Sales Cloud, there is no scheduling for it. If you need you can add specific Wait Activity as first step in the Journey.